# Angular promise in service

Tags: javascript, angular.js, promise

I'm new with Angular promise and I would like to know how to improve my code.

I have a service which preload media or data by calling an API.
The media API return an array of urls to preload.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp').service('PreloaderService', ['$http', '$q', 'localStorageService', function PreloaderService($http, $q, localStorageService) {
  this.preload = function(key){
    var current = 0;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    switch (key) {
      case 'media':
        // Simplified, in fact it call  a config service to get baseUrl
        var url = 'http://myapi/media';

        $http.get(url, {cache: true}).then(function(data) {
          var data = data.data;
          preloadImage(data, localStorageService.get('cachetoken'));
        }, function(data) {
          deferred.reject(data);
        });
        break;
      case 'data':
        var url = 'http://myapi/data';
        $http.get(url, {cache: true}).then(function(data) {
          var data = data.data;
          localStorageService.add('data', data);
          deferred.resolve(data);
        }, function(data) {
          deferred.reject(data);
        });
        break;
    }

    function preloadImage(arrayOfImages, cachetoken) {
      var promises = [];
      var totalImg = arrayOfImages.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < totalImg; i++) {
        (function(url, promise) {
          var img = new Image();
          img.onload = function() {
            var currentStatus = {
              currentImg: ++current,
              totalImg: totalImg
            };
            deferred.notify(currentStatus);
            promise.resolve();
          };
          img.src = url + '&tok=' + cachetoken;
        })(arrayOfImages[i], promises[i] = $.Deferred());
      }

      $.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
        deferred.resolve('RESOLVED');
      }).fail(function(data) {
        deferred.reject(data);
      });
    }

    return deferred.promise;
  };
}]);
```

And I call it with

```
  var promise = Preloader.preload('media');
  promise.then(
    function(){
      $rootScope.preload.imagesLoaded = true;
    },
    function(){},
    function(currentStatus){
      $rootScope.preload.currentImg = currentStatus.currentImg;
      $rootScope.preload.totalImg = currentStatus.totalImg;
    }
  );
```

Comment: I'm really trying hard not to be "that guy", but I can't help myself: "data" and "media" are plural forms already, so "datas" and "medias" isn't quite right. (The singular forms are "datum" and "medium", by the way.)

Comment: Too late, you're that guy ;)

Comment: Ahah you are totally right, I updated my question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This took a while to parse, it's probably me, I found few flaws with the code, except for a distinct lack of comments.

- I would have made `url` in `preload` an optional, 2nd parameter, I would probably want to call preload a few times with different URL's ( for 'data' )
- I think using a `switch` for `media` and `data` is overkill, I would have done a simple `if` statement.
- Since you have a number of times `function(data) {deferred.reject(data);});`, I would have assigned this to an actual function.
- `{cache: true}`, for `data` seem unfortunately hardcoded, consider this as well as optional parameter ?
- You define `current` on top, but `totalImg` in `preloadImage`, pick one spot and put both vars there
- Sometimes you postfix with `Img`, sometimes with `Images`. I would stick everywhere to `Images`, it is so much more readable
- Except for the `angular.module('myApp').service(` line, you have succinct lines of code, nice to read
- No need to store a shortcut to `data.data` in `var data = data.data;preloadImage(data, localStorageService.get('cachetoken'));`
- I would not have gone down the road of managing an array of promises, I probably would have done a simple `if (current===totalImg) deferred.resolve('RESOLVED');`
- `'RESOLVED'` seems kind of pointless to provide as a parameter to `resolve`, we know it's resolved ;) Perhaps `totalImg + ' images loaded'` ?